# Extract list values on a particular Properties, Linq

Tags: c#, linq

We can extract distinct value set from a list by using  following code

```
List<Person> distinctPeople = allPeople
  .GroupBy(p => new {p.PersonId, p.FavoriteColor} )
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Assume person has PersonId, FavoriteColor, age, address, etc..... My requirement is I would like to get a separate list which should contain distinct filter data only such as PersonId, FavoriteColor not others. What is the command for that, Assume I can create a small class which contain PersonId, FavoriteColor only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  List<Person> distinctPeople = allPeople
  .GroupBy(p => new {p.PersonId, p.FavoriteColor} )
  .Select(g => new {g.First().PersonId, g.First().FavouriteColor})
  .ToList();
```

**Update**

If you have your own class say `yourClass` with properties `PersonalId` and `FavouriteColor`, just change the select part to

```
.Select(g => new YourClass{PersonalId = g.First().PersonId, FavouriteColor = g.First().FavouriteColor})
```

Comment: Well, Assume I have small sub class which contain PersonId, FavoriteColor only, how I can cast the output to that

Comment: Yap. just change the select part to `.Select(g => new YourClass{PersonalId = g.First().PersonId, FavouriteColor = g.First().FavouriteColor})`

Answer (score 1):

You could just select what you want into a new class like this:

```
 .Select(g =>  new {g.PersonId, g.FavoriteColor})
```

The objects will include only what you selected, in this case, `PersonId` and `FavoriteColor`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension with custom `IEqualityComparer`, something like

```
List<Person> distinctPeople = allPeople
    .Distinct(new CustomEqualityComparer())
    .Select(p=> new{ p.PersonId, p.FavoriteColor})
    .ToList();
```